# How to schedule an SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

Is there another AWS service that would allow me to publish a Topic to SNS at in an arbitrary date in the future?

I've looked into using Cloudwatch Events but that seems to be more for recurring events while I need one-time events.

Comment: Have a recurring event that checks something (database, config file, etc.) to see if it's the right time for one of your one-time events to be processed.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to poll my database. If I could trigger an event the happen at a specific time that would take a lot of work off my servers.

Answer (score 2):

[Lambda scheduled events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html), You can create a lambda function that will publish to an SNS topic.

> You can create a Lambda function and direct AWS Lambda to execute it on a regular schedule. You can specify a fixed rate (for example, execute a Lambda function every hour or 15 minutes), or you can specify a Cron expression. For more information on expressions schedules, see [Schedule Expressions Using Rate or Cron.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)

Comment: I am aware of this but, again, this would more of a recurring cron-type schedule. What I need are more flexible one-time events that I can deploy the cloud and are triggered at a specific time defined by the event.

Comment: Could you be more specific when you say a one time event? How this event generated?

Comment: I guess you could use this method to publish event at least one month out

Comment: @jwerre actually Cron expressions include years